# Adaptive Cards in Carousel Layout FB Messenger Node.js?

Tags: node.js, botframework, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, adaptive-cards

Is it possible to have adaptive cards (rendered to an image and maybe a button mapped) sent in Carousel layout??

Or does Carousel layout only work for hero cards? If so is there a way to map an adaptive card to hero card?
I am using node.js

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Or does Carousel layout only work for hero cards?

No, you can refer to the sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/a91c425a89784130f8e9603762574737d145977c/samples/Integrated/BotFrameworkCarousel.json, simply leverage `session.sned(json)` and test in web chart or emulator, it will render as a Carousel.

Unfortunately, as mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status, adaptive cards in FB Messenger are simply rendered as images. And in my test, FB Messenger will to render with a Carousel. This should be the limitation or restriction in Messenger. Because I cannot find any where in the [Messenger Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/templates) what shows that it support Carousel template in FB Messenger.

Comment: I understand that the adaptive cards are rendered to images on fb messenger, however, this [Carousel card](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards) layout works with hero cards on fb messenger, and was wondering if there was a way to get the adaptive cards in the carousel layout.

Comment: Per my test, I cannot find a workaround. You can ask the feature request in Adaptive Card's GitHub at https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input, I made a feature request. https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1299